# SICP Exercise 2.19 - how to extend this?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, sicp

I am just exploring functional programming via SICP, and am wondering how I can extend Exercise 2.19 to do something more useful (and which seems to require side-effects).

The exercise involves a program that counts the number of ways one can make change for a given amount (in pennies) with a given a list of coin denominations. The solutions is quite simple (cc stands for "count-change"):

```
(define (cc amount coin-values)
  (cond ((= amount 0) 1)
        ((or (< amount 0) (no-more? coin-values)) 0)
        (else
         (+ (cc amount
                (except-first-denomination coin-values))
            (cc (- amount
                   (first-denomination coin-values))
                coin-values)))))

(define (first-denomination coinTypes) (car coinTypes))
(define (except-first-denomination coinTypes) (cdr coinTypes))
(define (no-more? coinTypes) (null? coinTypes))
```

You can see the relevant SICP section [here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html) and this links to description of the algorithm if above is not clear.

I first wanted to see what actual combinations of coins constitute each way to make change so I wrote my own version that prints out each solution as a list:

```
(define (count-change amount coinTypes)
    (define (cc amount coinTypes currChangeList)
        (cond ((= amount 0) 
                    (display (reverse currChangeList)) 
                    (newline) 
                    1)
              ((or (negative? amount) (null? coinTypes)) 
                    0)
              (else (+ (cc amount (cdr coinTypes) currChangeList)
                       (cc (- amount (car coinTypes)) coinTypes (cons (car coinTypes) currChangeList))))))
    (cc amount coinTypes ()))
```

So here's where I am stuck: I want to modify my method so that instead of returning an integer result = # of ways to make change, and simply printing each way during it's computation, I want it to return a list of the solutions (a list of lists, the length of which = # of ways to make change). However, I am at a loss of how to make this happen. It's easy to do in imperative/OO languages, but I can't figure out how to do it functionally.

Does anybody have any idea of how to achieve this? It seems like it should be a pretty easy thing to do for an experienced functional coder.. Please help satisfy my curiosity, and net yourself some coding karma :)

Thanks

Comment: Since solving a problem is much more fun than reading a solution: what if the result of `cc` wasn't the number of ways to make change, but a list of them?

Comment: thanks for the hint! you're right, solving a problem is much more fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define (count-change amount coinTypes)
    (define (cc amount coinTypes currChangeList)
        (cond ((= amount 0) 
               (list (reverse currChangeList)))
              ((or (negative? amount) (null? coinTypes)) 
               '())
              (else
                (append
                   (cc amount (cdr coinTypes) currChangeList)
                   (cc (- amount (car coinTypes))
                       coinTypes
                       (cons (car coinTypes) currChangeList))))))
    (cc amount coinTypes '()))
```

Comment: wrote question right before bed last night, and literally opened my eyes in the morning with the solution in my mind, hoping nobody had answered this... thanks for taking the time though. yours is more clean and elegant than mine when typed. have some karma :)